# Extracting server time with PHP and storing in MySQL - Unix time stamp OK?

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

All,

I'm trying to decide how to deal with time in a project which relies on (server) time intervals (in short, some content is available after user completed a specific action at least n hours before).  Right now, it seems like the easiest option would be to extract the Unix time stamp with `time()` and store it as is in MySQL.

Any reason why this is not a good idea?  Any gotcha I need to be aware of?  Performance impact?

Comment: Seconds divided by 60 is not hours.

Comment: Indeed.  Let me correct that, and thank you.  :-)

Answer (score 2):

Seems fine to me. Though you should probably store it as a **[`DATETIME`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/datetime.html)** and use **[`DateTime`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php)** objects, rather than UNIX timestamps and `time()`.

```
$time = new DateTime;
echo $time->format("Y-m-d H:i:s"); //Outputs current time, example: 2012-10-13 22:58:34
```

Comment: @DavidBélanger: Why would it be? Have you tested it?

Comment: @DavidBélanger I haven't seen any evidence of that.  You got a link?

Comment: @JDelage: Because you aren't dealing with NUMBERS, you're dealing with TIMES, which is both more readable, and easier to work with. You also get neat time related functions, such as DIFF to get the difference between 2 times, functions to get different segments of the time (hours, minutes, days), etc.

Comment: Because your indexes will be WAYY smaller and it take LESS space. See http://gpshumano.blogs.dri.pt/2009/07/06/mysql-datetime-vs-timestamp-vs-int-performance-and-benchmarking-with-myisam/ ...

Comment: Extra problem ... you require to init a class in PHP ... time() is faster in any way also and it's easier to do `time()-60`

Comment: @DavidBélanger: I hardly look at micro-optimizations, especially in PHP, if you wanted an efficient application, PHP isn't the way to go. I'm offering code with higher readability, robustness, and maintainability. Working with `time()` functions will leave you confused 4 months from now when you look at the code.

Answer (score 2):

Timestamps are fine. Don't divide them, it's unneeded calculation. If you plan to query (per object) about a timeout more often than update it then you would be better off storing the expiration time instead of the current (so calculating delta only once). Beware about DATETIME columns: they don't regard timezone setting, while your PHP does... so if you happen to have different timezone settings on different requests, then you're out of luck. Timestamps are absolute, and they also account for manace like daylight-savings times, where 3:01 is 2 minutes after 1:59...

Answer (score 1):

Actually, this is the best idea. The function `time()` give you the number of seconds from January 1th, 1970 00:00:00. There's no performance impact because it's only an `integer`. In MySQL, create a field like that `INT, 10, Unsigned`.

Time will give you performance on the SELECT and the WHERE. See http://gpshumano.blogs.dri.pt/2009/07/06/mysql-datetime-vs-timestamp-vs-int-performance-and-benchmarking-with-myisam/

The only problem you have is : time is limited to year 2038... but by the time 2038 come, the internal computer clock bytes will be larger ... hope so.

The other thing you may want to worrie about the DATETIME is : PHP time() run under UTC, while DATETIME depend on the timezone...

Stats when you do INSERT with 10000000 rows.

[image]

Stats when you SELECT / WHERE with indexes :

[image]

Comment: Wrong, the **best** thing is to use MySQL's DATETIME which is **optimized** for times, and also gives you neat functions like DIFF or HOUR etc.

Comment: I need to store the information for up to several months, with an hour level of detail.

Comment: @Paul Tomblin - why is that better?  Thanks.